# git shows untracked files on master but not on develop

Tags: git, git-untracked

I'm currently working on a branch made from **develop** branch, but theres a team that was working and commiting their work to **master** branch, so I added and commited all my stuff to my working branch.
I decided to merge master into develop, so I changed to **develop** made a *pull*, changed to **master** and made a *pull*... but if I do a *git status* it shows *untracked* files, if I switch back to **develop** and do *git status* the untracked files are gone, what am I missing?

**EDIT:**
adding more info
the repo is divided into two directories, one for frontend (I'm doing the source for frontend) and one directory for the backend code (the other team is working in this code). For some reason they started to work directly with master branch instead of develop, while I was pushing to develop. That why I needed to merge master into develop, so they can start working from develop and not master.

finished working on my feature-branch did:

```
- git add .
- git commit -m "commit message"

- git checkout develop
- git pull
(git says nothing to update)

- git checkout master
- git pull
(git says Fast-forward - 31 files changed, 1003 insertions(+), 63 deletions(-))
- git status
(git shows untracked directory)

- git checkout develop
- git status
(git doesn't show untracked directory)
```

**UPDATE:**
having checked out master, did:

```
 - git add .
```

(git started adding directories it shouldn't, like for example node_modules inside the frontend directory)

Could it be some sort of .gitignore missconfiguration?

Comment: Did the pull on master fail? What did git reply after the pull?

Comment: What do you mean by "made a pull"? Quote (as in cut-and-paste the text from) the actual commands you ran and their output, if possible.

Comment: @matt no problem at all 
- Fast-forward
- 31 files changed, 1003 insertions(+), 63 deletions(-)

Comment: @torek sure: 'git checkout master' then 'git pull'

Comment: Where did the untracked files come from? Are they stuff you just pulled or did you add them to the working folder?

Comment: So you ran: `git checkout master; git pull` and got `Fast-forward - 31 files changed, 1003 insertions(+), 63 deletions(-)` and then you ran `git checkout develop; git pull` and got the exact same message? (You said you ran `git pull` *twice*, but in your reply to @matt you show *one* output.) You obviously also ran some `git status` commands. Since `git pull` modifies your work-tree, it would help a lot to have a complete picture of where each command went in the sequence, where the `git status`-es were, and so on.

Comment: @matt I'm guessing from the develop branch structure, I can't see the files but the directory, added some info explaining the situation to help clarify

Comment: @torek sorry, added more info to try and clarify the issue and the steps I made

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say “finished working on my feature-branch”, does that mean there are actually _three_ branches in this story?

Comment: Also, I’ve never heard of “I can't see the files but the directory“ and there is no such thing as an untracked directory, git does not track directories and would not add one in and of itself.

Comment: @matt thanks for the edit. Yes, I work branching from develop, when I finish I merge into develop, but the problem is between develop and master I guess. When executing git status on master I get: "Untracked files:  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed) ./ " but when executin git add . thats when it shows me all the files that were untracked inside the ./ dir don't know if I'm making myself clear =/

Comment: Is there some sort of checkout hook on the server so that the gitignore differs per branch?

Comment: @matt not that I know of. First project that happens this stuff

Comment: My best guess here is there are different rules in `.gitignore` between the `master` and `develop` branch. You can compare them with the command `git diff master develop -- .gitignore`. What does this diff show?

Comment: Possible explanation: the directory is in `.gitignore` on `develop`, but some (not all) of its contents were added and committed. The files that weren't committed don't show as untracked on `develop` because they are ignored. When you check out master, the files that are committed on `develop` are deleted but the ones that are not committed are not deleted. This will show the directory as untracked when you do `git status`.